# Computer assignment 1 Int object not callable

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import math as m

year = 1996.
month = 9
day = 21
y2 = 96  # The number of years since 1900 with the simple subtraction of y2 = year - 1900

em = 0 (# An early-month correction factor that is either 0 or 1 using
    m.floor((14 - month)/ 12 ))

y3 = 96  (# year with early-month correction using
    y3 = y2 - em)

m2 = 9  (# month with early-month correction using
    m2 = month + 12*em)

l = 121.03 (# number of leap years since 1900 using the formula
    l = 1 + min(y3, 0) + m.floor(y3/4) - m.floor(y3/100) + m.floor((y3+300)/400))

d1 = 243 (# number of days preceding the given month in a non-leap year using
    d1 = m.floor(-1.63 + (m2 - 1)*30.6))

d2 = 35425.03 (# final excel date using
    d2 = day + y3 * 365 + l + d1)

print "Birth Excel Date at 0.00 hours into 1996-09-21: d2"
```

But there is an error here according to canopy:

```
22 
     23 em = 0 (# An early-month correction factor that is either 0 or 1 using
---> 24     m.floor((14 - month)/ 12 ))
     25 
     26 y3 = 96  (# year with early-month correction using

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Indeed it's because you use `(` instead of just `#`, this makes the program think you're trying to call something.

Comment: While there is nothing wrong with asking for help on assignments, this website typically is not meant to be the place for such things. Keep at it. Put in some debugging, especially in areas where you suspect the code may not be doing what you think it is, and keep trying.

Comment: @ouflak *"this website typically is not meant to be the place for such things"* Actually asking for homework help [is completely fine and acceptable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) provided you do so in a proper manner.

Comment: thanks for your input. But how would you do it in a proper manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the parentheses that wrap all your comments

```
x = 5  # This is a comment

y = 3 (#This is not a comment)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are failing because of how your comments are constructed:

```
em = 0 (# An early-month correction factor that is either 0 or 1 using
    m.floor((14 - month)/ 12 ))
```

Your parenthesis indicate that you are calling a function:

```
0()
```

This is not valid - which your error is telling you.

To correct this, remove the parenthesis:

```
em = 0 # An early-month correction factor that is either 0 or 1 using
```